# windows batch complex -o parameter for youtube-dl - how to properly format?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, special-characters, youtube-dl

The goal is a batch file which calls youtube-dl to save files to folders with this naming convention:

chapter number[space]chapter name\playlist index[space]title.ext

This attempt at passing an argument to windows youtube-dl fails:

-o "%(chapter_number)s %(chapter)s\%(playlist_index)s %(title)s.%(ext)s"

Windows has a less-than-proper method of parsing the command line (see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/twistylittlepassagesallalike/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way/ )

I've tried replacing the space characters with _ and adding ^ before the \ but that also fails.

There are many, many discussions about passing arguments which include special character TO batch files. This problem is about arguments being passed FROM a batch file.

I'm wondering how to pass this argument properly. There are 2 possibilities I'm trying unsuccessfully;

1) create a string of all the characters "%(chapter_number)s %(chapter)s\%(playlist_index)s %(title)s.%(ext)s", including the quotes, then pass the contents of the string...somehow

2) replace the space and \ characters with character sequences which will accurately pass the intended argument.

Would someone who has experience passing "problem" characters as command arguments from windows batch files please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well...yet again an answer shows up just after the question is posted:

-o "%%(playlist)s/%%(chapter_number)s %%(chapter)s/%%(playlist_index)s %%(title)s.%%(ext)s"

Comment: Often a good description to a problem leads to a better search for an answer